# Error while creating S3 Client in Java

Tags: java, eclipse, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I'm having a problem.

I have a Java project that works fine (written by someone else), I cloned it to my computer (from GitHub) and opened it in Eclipse. When I'm trying to run it, I keep getting an error when the script tries to create a s3 client.

This is the code (this.client = AmazonS3Client instance):

```
ClientConfiguration clientConfiguration = new ClientConfiguration();
ClientConfiguration.setMaxConnections(10);
clientConfiguration.setConnectionTimeout(120000);
clientConfiguration.setSocketTimeout(120000);
clientConfiguration.setMaxErrorRetry(5);

this.client = new AmazonS3Client(new InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider(), clientConfiguration);
```

This is the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper
    at com.amazonaws.internal.config.InternalConfig.<clinit>(InternalConfig.java:43)
    at com.amazonaws.internal.config.InternalConfig$Factory.<clinit>(InternalConfig.java:304)
    at com.amazonaws.util.VersionInfoUtils.userAgent(VersionInfoUtils.java:142)
    at com.amazonaws.util.VersionInfoUtils.initializeUserAgent(VersionInfoUtils.java:137)
    at com.amazonaws.util.VersionInfoUtils.getUserAgent(VersionInfoUtils.java:100)
    at com.amazonaws.ClientConfiguration.<clinit>(ClientConfiguration.java:64)
```

I tried also "this.client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.defaultClient();" with a "Amazon3Client" instance, but it didn't work as well - same problem, error when trying to define ClientConfiguration...

I'm using aws-java-sdk-1.11.160.jar (tried before with 1.11.111 and didn't work, so I thought maybe upgrading the jar would help... it didn't)

I'm on this a couple of days now, and I can't seem to find the problem...
Any help would be great... Thank you!

Comment: mate, if you think you have all the dependencies, then this issue normally happens when you have two different versions of a package imported.

Answer (score 1):

You miss the `jackson-databind` jar in your classpath.

If you use maven, you can add the following dependency to solve this error:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version><your version></version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I'm not using Maven, and in my .classpath file I gave "<classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/jar/com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jar"/>"

Answer (score 0):

This code is written to grab the AWS secret and access key from the EC2 instance profile. When you clone it locally you'll need to provide a different way to authenticate to the AWS API.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/credentials.html

When constructing the client this code is using the option for a [IAM instance profile](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_use_switch-role-ec2_instance-profiles.html)

`new InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider(),`

> Credentials provider implementation that loads credentials from the Amazon EC2 Instance Metadata Service.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/auth/InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider.html

Comment: @strongiz - I already set the AWS Access & Secret ID's in the "Environment Variables" in the "Run Configurations" - the error comes from the new ClientConfiguration instance, not from the line that needs to take credentials... (Meaning - from the first line in the code!)